# Text won't go inside border in HTML

Tags: html, css, border

I have the the following HTML:

```
<div class="outf">
    <h3 class="left">Text</h3>
    <h3 class="right">more text</h3>
    <p><h3 class="right">some more text/h3></p>
</div>
```

and in the CSS I have:

```
.outf {border-color: #3377bb; border-style: double; border-width: 2px; 
   width: 750px; padding: 8px;}

.right {text-align: right; float: right;}

.left {text-align: left; float: left;}
```

I want the h3 headings to be inside the border but for some reason the border appears first and the text appears below it. Anyone know why this is? 
Thanks.

Comment: For the record, you can't have an `<h3>` in a `<p>`.

Comment: indeed, that's invalid and it can possibly create you problems in IE

Comment: Cheers. Was silly to put that in. A <br /> is what I should be using I think.

Comment: nop, <br> is presentational element, not so semantic so avoid it. You can just clear:both in your h3. http://jsfiddle.net/ZJHEe/ (I also answered.)

Comment: @George Katsanos: `<br>` is not purely presentational. It's just that people abuse it as a presentational element - and indeed, it would be inappropriate to use it here as well.

Comment: dear see my answer and let me know is this you want or something else.

Comment: Boltlock: you can agree that if used in this case, it would be clearly presentational:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it, set the `overflow` property on the `div`:

```
.outf { overflow:hidden; /* other definitions */ }
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/2E5Jw/

---

More on the topic - http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: Thank you Xander. That sorted it.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` does not **clear** floats *per se*. It does tell a container to **contain** its floats, however, which is subtly different.

Answer (score 1):

u can use the flowiing

```
overflow: auto;
```

inside the `.outf` `div`, so that it will provide a scroll-bar and will cause the div to get extended auonmatically, when the text exceeds...

writting `overflow:hidden;` will make your text gets hidden inside the div...

Comment: No; it won't. Not in this situation; `overflow: hidden` will simply make the container element expand to encompass its floated children.

Comment: No, `overflow: auto` allows the browser to display scroll bars or expand as it determines (within other constraints). An element with `overflow: hidden`, with floated child elements, will expand to encompass those elements. Have a look at [Xander's JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2E5Jw/1/) (albeit I updated it to properly close an the closing `</h3>` tag).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the complete and proper solution is clearfix. I think that's also the ultimate article: http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/ http://jsfiddle.net/ZJHEe/

Answer (score 0):

See the fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CqJVs/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CqJVs/embedded/result/

Its just a float issue nothing else. problem solved.